# Navigate to different fragments in another nav graph

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have to navigate from fragment in module 1 and navgraph #1 (let's call it `first_nav_graph`) to different fragments in another module and another navgraph #2 (let's call it `second_nav_graph`).

When I navigate to startDestination of `second_nav_graph` it works correctly - I just include `second_nav_graph` to `first_nav_graph` and create action:

```
 <include app:graph="@navigation/second_nav_graph" />
...

 <dialog
        android:id="@+id/card_menu_fragment"
        android:name="ru.bank.mobile.presentation.ui.product_menus.CardMenuFragment"
        android:label="CardMenuFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu">
     <action
         android:id="@+id/actionCardMenuFragmentToSecondNavGraph"
         app:destination="@id/second_nav_graph"/>
```

So we can easily navigate to startDestination of `second_nav_graph`. The problem is that I need to navigate to two different fragments of `second_nav_graph`. I added such actions to `first_nav_graph`:

```
 <include app:graph="@navigation/second_nav_graph" />
...

 <dialog
        android:id="@+id/card_menu_fragment"
        android:name="ru.bank.mobile.presentation.ui.product_menus.CardMenuFragment"
        android:label="CardMenuFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu">
     <action // navigates correctly
         android:id="@+id/actionCardMenuFragmentToSecondNavGraph"
         app:destination="@id/second_nav_graph"/>

    <action // app crashes
        android:id="@+id/actionCardMenuFragmentToIncreaseLimitFragment"
        app:destination="@id/increaseLimitFragment" />

    <action // app crashes
        android:id="@+id/actionCardMenuFragmentToIncreaseLimitStatusFragment"
        app:destination="@id/increaseLimitStatusFragment" />
```

But when I push button that navigates to specific fragment in `second_nav_graph` (with `findNavController().navigate()`) my app crashes with exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.otpbank.mobile, PID: 11072
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination ru.otpbank.mobile:id/increaseLimitFragment referenced from action ru.otpbank.mobile:id/actionCardMenuFragmentToIncreaseLimitFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(ru.otpbank.mobile:id/card_menu_fragment) label=CardMenuFragment
```

`second_nav_graph.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/second_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/increaseLimitFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/increaseLimitFragment"
        android:name="com.example.credit_limit_increase.limit_increase_application.IncreaseLimitFragment"
        android:label="IncreaseLimitFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/increaseLimitStatusFragment"
        android:name="com.example.credit_limit_increase.limit_increase_status.IncreaseLimitStatusFragment"
        android:label="fragment_increase_limit_status"
/>
</navigation>
```

Could you please help me to understand the reason of this behavior and any ways to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphshttps://) that the only way to access another graph is through its startDestination:

> The nested graph encapsulates its destinations. As with a root graph,
> a nested graph must have a destination identified as the start
> destination. Destinations outside of the nested graph, such as those
> on the root graph, access the nested graph **only through its start**
> **destination.**

So it seems like there are no ways to navigate to different fragments of a nested graph from another graph.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).